# Using the WinAPI AnimateWindow function in the inno setup installer

Tags: winapi, inno-setup

I'm trying to add an exit animation to my installer window.

I used WinAPI's `AnimateWindow` function for this purpose.

My code is as follows:

```
[Code]
function AnimateWindow(hWnd: Integer; dwTime, dwFlags: DWORD): Boolean;
external 'AnimateWindow@User32.dll stdcall';

Const
  AW_HIDE = $10000;
  AW_CENTER = $10;

{...}

procedure DeinitializeSetup();  
begin 
  AnimateWindow(WizardForm.Handle, 1500, AW_HIDE or AW_CENTER);
end;
```

But, for some reason, the animation only applies to the inside of the window, while the borders disappear only at the end of the animation, which makes the animation look bad.

What can I fix in the code so that the animation appears properly?

---

I have tried adding this line:

`WizardForm.BorderStyle: = bsNone;`

before calling the function to conceal the boundaries before the animation. But I'm looking for a more "real" solution.

Comment: I guess WizardForm isn't the top-level window, but a child window. You could try calling `GetParent` to get the parent window, if Inno doesn't provide this value for you.

Comment: About 'GetParent' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getparent

Comment: I don't know much about the language you provide, but I have tested it in my Win32 desktop application and found it works for the main form. To see if this function works, you need to check the following.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-animatewindow#return-value

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT Thanks for your help, but it does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: `MainForm.Handle`?

Comment: I tried, and it did not animate at all.

Comment: Have you tried calling AnimateWindow near the front of the application? Not at the end of the DeinitializeSetup.

Comment: @Junjie Zhu - MSFT, Where do you think I should call the AnimateWindow function?
I want it to occur when closing the installer.

Comment: In Win32, I called this function at the earliest place I could get the main form handle.